# 1064 error, Not sure what the issue is

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting this error when submitting. I have checked my form 10x and I cannot figure out what is wrong with it.

Here is the error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE order_num = '5293528'' at line 1

Here is the form code

```
public function next()
 {
    try
    {

        if(isset($_POST['giventoatpdate']))
        {
            $update = trim($_POST['update']);
            $orders = $_SESSION['order_nums'];
            $st=$this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `orders` (giventoatpdate) VALUES (:upd) WHERE order_num = :orderr");
            $st->bindparam(":upd", $update);
            $st->bindparam(":orderr", $orders);
            $st->execute();
            return $st;

        }

      $order = $_GET['uid'];
      $stmt=$this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_num = :order");
      $stmt->execute(array(":order"=>$order));
      $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($row['giventoatpdate'] = ' ')
    {
        echo 
        "
        <form name='atpdate' method='POST'>
        Date Sent to clown?
        <br>
        <input type='text' name='update'>
        <br>
        <input type='submit' name='giventoatpdate'>
        </form>
        ";
    }
```

Everything else is working fine. It gives me this error when I hit submit.

Comment: **A:** It's because INSERT doesn't have a WHERE clause. Now read the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html - INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE does. Or, you may have intended to do an UPDATE. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html - I'm thinking you want to do an UPDATE here.

Comment: Your element was named correctly, `update`..

Comment: *I smell an answer being formulated...* - My Spidey sense is tingling and someone is typing like a mental case to get one in.

Comment: @OP.  I've made a few edits to my answer and one of those being in regards to something else: `if($row['giventoatpdate'] = ' ')` You're "assigning" rather than doing a comparison. Do reload it if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing somebody popped in an answer...

It's because INSERT doesn't have a WHERE clause.

Now read the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html

INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE does.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Or, you may have intended to do an UPDATE. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html

Seeing `$update = trim($_POST['update']);` the operative word being "update" in the POST array, I'm thinking you want to do an UPDATE here rather than an INSERT, since you are dealing with orders taken from your site.

So, you have a few choices here.

If it's an UPDATE, your query would read as:

```
UPDATE `orders` 
SET giventoatpdate = :upd 
WHERE order_num = :orderr
```

Check for errors:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

**Footnotes:**

Seeing `if($row['giventoatpdate'] = ' ')` you do realize that this checks for a "space" rather than `if($row['giventoatpdate'] = '')` to check if it's "empty".

You're also "assigning" rather than doing a "comparison" here which should read as:

`if($row['giventoatpdate'] == '')`

If you're checking for empty'ness, then remove the space in there, or you can do

```
if(empty($row['giventoatpdate']))
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: empty is not working. I did empty on all three, I put info into giventoatpdate and even with empty it is still showing that form and not going on to the next one.

Comment: @Kmiles1990123 it will depend as to what exactly is in that row that you're querying for. Run a `var_dump()` to see what it contains in there. However, if `if($row['giventoatpdate'] = ' ')` does work for you now, then stay with that.

Comment: its a date in that row, it reads 2/10/16 and no, How I had it set was not working.

Comment: Sidenote, This has to be the best answer I have ever received on this site, Very descriptive. Thanks man!

Comment: @Kmiles1990123 Thanks for the compliment and you're most welcome, glad I could help, *cheers!*

Answer (score 1):

INSERT doesn't have WHERE operator.
You need to change query to something like this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET my_field = :new_value WHERE my_another_filed = :another_value_or_row_id
```